# Hurry up!The programme will start/is about to start

Tags: present-tense, future-tense

Hurry up!The programme will start/is about to start.

My Approach:

Here also I think both can be used in reference that the programme will start in future and they will miss

Or

The programme is about to start indicating very recent action.

But the Ans given  (is about to start)

Am I right in my approach.Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is "hurry" indicating an action is happening soon, so "about to".

"Will" compared with "about to" should refer to an action happening in a further future, perhaps "will start at 10pm sharp".